# Does Psychosis Crawler die in the middle of Days Undoing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Okay, so I have a commander deck that allows me to draw my entire library and I stumbled upon a strange situation.

This is the chain of events I want to happen:

1. Tap [Niv-Mizzet, the Firemind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNiv-Mizzet%2c%20the%20Firemind%5d) with [Curiosity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCuriosity%5d) attached to form an
   infinite draw combo.
2. Cast [Psychosis Crawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPsychosis%20Crawler%5d)
3. Cast [Day's Undoing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDay%27s%5d%2b%5bUndoing%5d) to return my hand and graveyard to my library and draw 7, reactivating the combo with [Niv-Mizzet, the Firemind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNiv-Mizzet%2c%20the%20Firemind%5d) and [Curiosity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCuriosity%5d)

My question is, during the resolution of Day's Undoing, Psychosis Crawler's power and toughness will be reduced to 0 before I draw my 7 cards (as far as I'm aware?). Does this mean he will die before I activate the draw combo again to win?

Comment: Is the Niv-Mizzet part of the question really necessary?

Comment: @JonTheMon To me it adds a bit of context to why I am using this combo

Comment: But the actual interaction you're looking at is Psychosis Crawler and Days Undoing.  And even that can be boiled down to Crawler and any wheel effect.

Comment: I'm confused... wouldn't you have won the game after step 1, before you ever get a chance to cast any of the other things?

Comment: Or is the issue simply that the Niv + Curiosity combo can only deal about 85-90 damage before you run out of cards to draw, which wouldn't be enough in a Commander game to kill all opponents?

Comment: @GendoIkari Thats the problem. in a multiplayer game i cant kill everyone before I Deck myself and lose. I will be looking for a Laboratory Maniac to further prevent that eventuality. however with Psychosis it deals damage to all opponents giving another possible win con. I may also rely on Fabricate and other tutors to make sure i have Psychosis on the field in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Psychosis Crawler won't die during the resolution of Day's Undoing.  Toughness check is done as a state-based action.  State-based actions are checked after each spell/trigger is done resolving.

> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 116, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event. If any ...
>
> 704.4. Unlike triggered abilities, state-based actions pay no attention to what happens during the resolution of a spell or ability.

Comment: Re "*State-based actions are checked after spells/triggers are done resolving.*", That makes it sound like they are performed after all spells/abilities on the stack are done resolving, but that's wrong. I suggest the following alternate wording: State-based actions aren't checked during the resolution of a spell or ability; they are only checked when a player would get priority.

Comment: Note that triggers, on the hand, are constantly checked, if permanent had an ability that triggered "whenever a creature is reduced to zero toughness", it would trigger.

Comment: @ikegami Just had a brain wave, does that mean that I wouldnt have to untap Niv mizzet because during Days undoing, the 7 card draw would initiate the combo with Curiosity again right? Essentially meaning I could cut  Dramatic Reversal out of this situation?

Comment: @ThunderToes, Correct.

Comment: Wonderful. Less manna to enable this then :)